# Is this ceiling pendant double insulated?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I bought this ceiling rose off Amazon (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Modern-Antique-Brass-Ceiling-Lighting/dp/B00CJ9GE9Q):

[image]

It's not like others I've seen as it has a black input sheath to a connection box, which also closes over the top. Does this mean it is double insulated?

[image]

Thanks

Read more: http://www.diynot.com/diy/threads/is-this-ceiling-rose-double-insulated.455292/#ixzz42hkRqkKZ

Answer (score 1):

No. Class 2 (double insulated) devices are not fitted with a ground wire, and must not be grounded. Instead, they're constructed with much sturdier insulation to ensure that exposed parts cannot become live, even in the event of a fault occuring.

They're also required to display the double insulated symbol; a square within a square.

The cover over the terminal strip is to protect against fingers or metallic objects falling into the terminals.

Answer (score 0):

Fixtures are rarely double insulated, but that rarely matters. It has a ground wire. Make sure that's properly connected, and it'll be as safe as if it was double insulated. Maybe safer.

Answer (score 0):

The ground wire serves the same purpose as double-insulating, from the standpoint of human safety, presuming it is connected properly.

One note is that you should use a tester of some kind to determine which one of those black-insulated wires is the "hot" (or line) and which one is the "neutral" (grounded conductor). You want to connect the incoming hot conductor to the wire that is connected to the base of the socket, not to the wire that connects to the threads in the socket. The light itself doesn't care, but the problem is that if you connect the live wire to the threads, there is a greater shock hazard for humans.